# bokeh not showing in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am unable to plot even the most basic of Bokeh plots in Jupyter Notebook. I had a search and can see that this was a reported problem a little over a year ago but nothing since - is it still an issue for others?

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=15, line_color="navy", 
fill_color="orange", fill_alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```

I get the "BokehJS 0.12.10 successfully loaded." message, but not plot. Note that it outputs html files ok.

I've tried changing the environment variables using:

```
import os
os.environ['BOKEH_RESOURCES'] = 'inline'
```

But this has not effect either. It's bee a frustrating afternoon so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your version of the notebook is too old. There is no technical path to simultaneously supporting both the new JupyterLab and classic notebook versions older than 5.0, at all. Supporting JupyterLab is an imperative, so as of recently, Bokeh can only support classic notebook 5.0 and newer. So, you can:

- downgrade Bokeh (<= 0.12.8), or
- updgrade Jupyter Notebook (>= 5.0), or
- switch to recent JupyterLab betas. You will need to install the Jupyter extension with

  ```
    jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_bokeh
  ```

Comment: thanks @bigreddot, I thought I was up to date with Jupyter but was getting mixed up with too many venvs. All sorted by upgrading Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 14):

Running the lines below worked for me

```
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
import bokeh.io
from bokeh import *
bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)
```

Comment: Works for JupyterLab. And `from bokeh import *` not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is documented:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.2/docs/user_guide/jupyter.html

```
import itertools

import numpy as np

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

TOOLS = "crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover,save"

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("(x, y)", "($x, $y)"),
    ("radius", "@radius"),
    ("fill color", "$color[hex, swatch]:colors"),
    ("foo", "@foo"),
    ("bar", "@bar"),
]

N = 26 * 26
x, y = np.mgrid[0:101:4, 0:101:4].reshape((2, N))

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    radius=np.random.random(N) * 0.4 + 1.7,
    colors=np.array([(r, g, 150) for r, g in zip(50+2*x, 30+2*y)], dtype="uint8"),
    foo=list(itertools.permutations("abcdef"))[:N],
    bar=np.random.normal(size=N),
    text=[str(i) for i in np.arange(N)],
))

p = figure(title="Hoverful Scatter", tools=TOOLS, tooltips=TOOLTIPS)

r = p.circle("x", "y", radius="radius", source=source,
             fill_color="colors", fill_alpha=0.6, line_color=None)
p.hover.renderers = [r] # hover only for circles

p.text("x", "y", text="text", source=source, alpha=0.5,
       text_font_size="7px", text_baseline="middle", text_align="center")

show(p, notebook_handle=True)
```