# Bokeh/panel won't render in-line with Jupyter Lab

Tags: bokeh, panel, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to visualize Bokeh plots and panels with a Bokeh backend in a notebook in JupyterLab. Things were running fine until I updated.

Current packages and versions are below

I have tried the following:

```
conda install jupyter_bokeh
conda install -c pyviz panel holoviews
```

```
conda install -c pyviz bokeh panel holoviews`
jupyter labextension install --no-build @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`
```

```
jupyter lab clean
```

```
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

As well as the following from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893131/bokeh-not-showing-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
import bokeh.io
from bokeh import *
bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)
```

Here is a toy example from the post cited above. I do see `BokehJS 2.2.3 successfully loaded`, but the plot does not render. There is no other error. I've tried the toy example with various permutations of the above substituted for the first two lines with no effect.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=15, line_color="navy", 
fill_color="orange", fill_alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```

I'd really appreciate any insight - I'm still not great at upgrading Jupyter Labs and getting Bokeh/Panels to render properly in-line. Thank you

current installed packages:

```
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
alsa-lib                  1.2.3                h516909a_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.2.1            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h497a2fe_2    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.9.1              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bibtexparser              1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.35.1               h193b22a_2    conda-forge
binutils_linux-64         2.35                h67ddf6f_30    conda-forge
bioconductor-biobase      2.50.0            r40hd029910_1    bioconda
bioconductor-biocgenerics 0.36.0            r40hdfd78af_1    bioconda
bioconductor-biocparallel 1.24.1            r40h399db7b_0    bioconda
bioconductor-biostrings   2.58.0            r40hd029910_1    bioconda
bioconductor-dada2        1.18.0            r40h399db7b_1    bioconda
bioconductor-delayedarray 0.16.3            r40hd029910_0    bioconda
bioconductor-genomeinfodb 1.26.4            r40hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata 1.2.4             r40hdfd78af_2    bioconda
bioconductor-genomicalignments 1.26.0            r40hd029910_1    bioconda
bioconductor-genomicranges 1.42.0            r40hd029910_1    bioconda
bioconductor-iranges      2.24.1            r40hd029910_0    bioconda
bioconductor-matrixgenerics 1.2.1             r40hdfd78af_0    bioconda
bioconductor-rhtslib      1.22.0            r40hd029910_1    bioconda
bioconductor-rsamtools    2.6.0             r40h399db7b_1    bioconda
bioconductor-s4vectors    0.28.1            r40hd029910_0    bioconda
bioconductor-shortread    1.48.0            r40h399db7b_1    bioconda
bioconductor-summarizedexperiment 1.20.0            r40hdfd78af_1    bioconda
bioconductor-xvector      0.30.0            r40hd029910_1    bioconda
bioconductor-zlibbioc     1.36.0            r40hd029910_1    bioconda
biom-format               2.1.10           py38h0b5ebd8_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.1                    openblas    conda-forge
blast                     2.11.0          pl526he19e7b1_0    bioconda
bleach                    3.3.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
bokeh                     2.3.1            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
bowtie2                   2.4.2            py38hc2f83ea_2    bioconda
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h497a2fe_1001    conda-forge
bwidget                   1.9.14               ha770c72_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               h7f98852_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.5.30            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cachecontrol              0.12.6                     py_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            h6cf1ce9_1008    conda-forge
certifi                   2021.5.30        py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.5           py38ha65f79e_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py38h578d9bd_1    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
colorcet                  2.0.6                      py_0    pyviz
cryptography              3.4.7            py38ha5dfef3_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.76.1               h979ede3_1    conda-forge
cutadapt                  3.4              py38h4a8c8d9_1    bioconda
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
cython                    0.29.23          py38h709712a_1    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.6               h48d8840_2    conda-forge
deblur                    1.1.0                      py_2    bioconda
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dendropy                  4.5.2              pyh3252c3a_0    bioconda
dnaio                     0.5.0            py38h4a8c8d9_1    bioconda
emperor                   1.0.3            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
entrez-direct             13.9            pl5262he881be0_2    bioconda
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
expat                     2.3.0                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
fastcluster               1.1.26           py38hc5bc63f_2    conda-forge
fasttree                  2.1.10                        0    bioconda
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            hba837de_1005    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h0708190_1    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.10               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
gcc_impl_linux-64         9.3.0               h70c0ae5_19    conda-forge
gcc_linux-64              9.3.0               hf25ea35_30    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h0b5b191_1005    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    9.3.0               hc4a2995_19    conda-forge
gfortran_linux-64         9.3.0               hdc58fab_30    conda-forge
glib                      2.68.1               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.68.1               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
gneiss                    0.4.6                      py_0    bioconda
graphite2                 1.3.13            h58526e2_1001    conda-forge
gsl                       2.6                  he838d99_2    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.18.4               hf529b03_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.18.4               h76c114f_2    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         9.3.0               hd87eabc_19    conda-forge
gxx_linux-64              9.3.0               h3fbe746_30    conda-forge
h5py                      3.2.1           nompi_py38h9915d05_100    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  2.8.0                h83ec7ef_1    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h6a2412b_1114    conda-forge
hdmedians                 0.14.2           py38h5c078b8_0    conda-forge
hmmer                     3.1b2                         3    bioconda
holoviews                 1.14.4                     py_0    pyviz
htslib                    1.12                 h9093b5e_1    bioconda
icu                       68.1                 h58526e2_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ijson                     3.1.3              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        3.10.1           py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.5.3            py38hd0cf306_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.22.0           py38hd0cf306_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.6.3              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
iqtree                    2.1.2                h56fc30b_0    bioconda
isa-l                     2.30.0               ha770c72_4    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py38h578d9bd_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
jupyter_bokeh             3.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                3.0.16             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              h77966d4_13    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py38h1fd1430_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.17.2               h926e7f8_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 hddcbb42_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                8_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                8_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  11.1.0          default_ha53f305_1    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.76.1               hc4aaa36_1    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.7                  h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               hcdb4288_3    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h58526e2_2    conda-forge
libgcc                    7.2.0                h69d50b8_2    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     9.3.0               h7864c58_19    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libglib                   2.68.1               h3e27bee_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                8_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm11                 11.1.0               hf817b99_2    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               h812cca2_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.12          pthreads_h4812303_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h21135ba_2    conda-forge
libpq                     13.1                 hfd2b0eb_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha56f1ee_6    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  9.3.0               hb016644_19    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               h6de172a_19    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.2.0                hbd63e13_2    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libuv                     1.41.0               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.0                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               h72842e0_4    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.33               h15afd5d_2    conda-forge
lockfile                  0.12.2                     py_1    conda-forge
lxml                      4.6.3            py38hf1fe3a4_0    conda-forge
lz4                       3.1.3            py38hebdc3cf_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
mafft                     7.475                h779adbc_1    bioconda
make                      4.3                  hd18ef5c_1    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38h497a2fe_3    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.4.1            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.4.1            py38hcc49a3a_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h497a2fe_1004    conda-forge
more-itertools            8.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
msgpack-python            1.0.2            py38h1fd1430_1    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.23               ha770c72_2    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.23               h935591d_2    conda-forge
natsort                   7.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbclassic                 0.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.0.7            py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h58526e2_4    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  2.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nodejs                    15.14.0              h92b4a50_0    conda-forge
nose                      1.3.7                   py_1006    conda-forge
notebook                  6.3.0              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
nspr                      4.30                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
nss                       3.64                 hb5efdd6_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.20.2           py38h9894fe3_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
openblas                  0.3.12          pthreads_h04b7a96_1    conda-forge
openjdk                   11.0.1            h516909a_1016    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                hb52868f_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
packaging                 20.9               pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.2.4            py38h1abd341_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.12                 h7f98852_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
panel                     0.11.3                     py_0    pyviz
pango                     1.48.4               hb8ff022_1    conda-forge
param                     1.11.1                     py_0    pyviz
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.44                 he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.36                h032f7d1_1    conda-forge
perl                      5.26.2            h36c2ea0_1008    conda-forge
perl-app-cpanminus        1.7044                  pl526_1    bioconda
perl-archive-tar          2.32                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-base                 2.23                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-business-isbn        3.004                   pl526_0    bioconda
perl-business-isbn-data   20140910.003            pl526_0    bioconda
perl-carp                 1.38                    pl526_3    bioconda
perl-common-sense         3.74                    pl526_2    bioconda
perl-compress-raw-bzip2   2.087           pl526he1b5a44_0    bioconda
perl-compress-raw-zlib    2.087           pl526hc9558a2_0    bioconda
perl-constant             1.33                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-data-dumper          2.173                   pl526_0    bioconda
perl-digest-hmac          1.03                    pl526_3    bioconda
perl-digest-md5           2.55                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-encode               2.88                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-encode-locale        1.05                    pl526_6    bioconda
perl-exporter             5.72                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-exporter-tiny        1.002001                pl526_0    bioconda
perl-extutils-makemaker   7.36                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-file-listing         6.04                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-file-path            2.16                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-file-temp            0.2304                  pl526_2    bioconda
perl-html-parser          3.72            pl526h6bb024c_5    bioconda
perl-html-tagset          3.20                    pl526_3    bioconda
perl-html-tree            5.07                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-http-cookies         6.04                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-http-daemon          6.01                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-http-date            6.02                    pl526_3    bioconda
perl-http-message         6.18                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-http-negotiate       6.01                    pl526_3    bioconda
perl-io-compress          2.087           pl526he1b5a44_0    bioconda
perl-io-html              1.001                   pl526_2    bioconda
perl-io-socket-ssl        2.066                   pl526_0    bioconda
perl-io-zlib              1.10                    pl526_2    bioconda
perl-json                 4.02                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-json-xs              2.34            pl526h6bb024c_3    bioconda
perl-libwww-perl          6.39                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-list-moreutils       0.428                   pl526_1    bioconda
perl-list-moreutils-xs    0.428                   pl526_0    bioconda
perl-lwp-mediatypes       6.04                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-lwp-protocol-https   6.07                    pl526_4    bioconda
perl-mime-base64          3.15                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-mozilla-ca           20180117                pl526_1    bioconda
perl-net-http             6.19                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-net-ssleay           1.88            pl526h90d6eec_0    bioconda
perl-ntlm                 1.09                    pl526_4    bioconda
perl-parent               0.236                   pl526_1    bioconda
perl-pathtools            3.75            pl526h14c3975_1    bioconda
perl-scalar-list-utils    1.52            pl526h516909a_0    bioconda
perl-socket               2.027                   pl526_1    bioconda
perl-storable             3.15            pl526h14c3975_0    bioconda
perl-test-requiresinternet 0.05                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-time-local           1.28                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-try-tiny             0.30                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-types-serialiser     1.0                     pl526_2    bioconda
perl-uri                  1.76                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-www-robotrules       6.02                    pl526_3    bioconda
perl-xml-namespacesupport 1.12                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-xml-parser           2.44_01         pl5262hc3e0081_1002    conda-forge
perl-xml-sax              1.02                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-xml-sax-base         1.09                    pl526_0    bioconda
perl-xml-sax-expat        0.51                    pl526_3    bioconda
perl-xml-simple           2.25                    pl526_1    bioconda
perl-xsloader             0.24                    pl526_0    bioconda
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pigz                      2.6                  h27826a3_0    conda-forge
pillow                    8.1.2            py38ha0e1e83_1    conda-forge
pip                       21.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    0.13.1           py38h578d9bd_4    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.10.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.18             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.8.0            py38h497a2fe_1    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
py                        1.10.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pyct                      0.4.8                      py_0    pyviz
pyct-core                 0.4.8                      py_0    pyviz
pygments                  2.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.12.3           py38h578d9bd_7    conda-forge
pyqt-impl                 5.12.3           py38h7400c14_7    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18          py38h709712a_7    conda-forge
pyqtchart                 5.12             py38h7400c14_7    conda-forge
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1           py38h7400c14_7    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py38h497a2fe_2    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
pytest                    6.2.3            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
python                    3.8.8           hffdb5ce_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python-isal               0.10.0           py38h497a2fe_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyviz_comms               2.1.0                      py_0    pyviz
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py38h497a2fe_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     22.0.3           py38h2035c66_1    conda-forge
qiime2                    2021.4.0                 py38_0    qiime2/label/r2021.4
qt                        5.12.9               hda022c4_4    conda-forge
raxml                     8.2.12               h779adbc_3    bioconda
readline                  8.1                  h46c0cb4_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
requests-unixsocket       0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
samtools                  1.12                 h9aed4be_1    bioconda
scikit-bio                0.5.6            py38h0b5ebd8_4    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.24.1           py38h658cfdd_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.6.2            py38h7b17777_0    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.11.1               hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.11.1             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
sed                       4.8                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
sepp                      4.3.10           py38h3252c3a_2    bioconda
setuptools                49.6.0           py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38h578d9bd_1    conda-forge
sortmerna                 2.0                  he860b03_4    bioconda
sqlite                    3.35.4               h74cdb3f_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.12.2           py38h5c078b8_0    conda-forge
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                h77966d4_13    conda-forge
tbb                       2020.2               h4bd325d_4    conda-forge
terminado                 0.9.4            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h21135ba_1    conda-forge
tktable                   2.10                 hb7b940f_3    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py38h497a2fe_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.61.2             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0    conda-forge
tzlocal                   2.1                pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
unifrac                   0.20.2           py38hc37a69a_1    bioconda
urllib3                   1.26.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vsearch                   2.7.0                         1    bioconda
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          0.57.0           py38h578d9bd_4    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1            py38h578d9bd_4    conda-forge
xopen                     1.1.0            py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.7.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.2.1                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h516909a_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1010    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.9                ha95c52a_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: If your conda list shows Bokeh 2.3.1 but the notebook output shows `BokehJS 0.12.10 successfully loaded` then you have some environment corruption or mixup, and the notebook is not actually loading the version of Bokeh you intend. A common cause is that the notebook itself is running from a different environment than you think it is. For reference Bokeh 0.12.10 is ***ancient***, nearly half a decade old, and I can guarantee it is too old to be compatible with any version of Holoviews.

Comment: Thank you @bigreddot. I re-built the env from scratch, same problem, but I do now get "BokehJS 2.2.3 successfully loaded." with the toy example, but still no plot. Perhaps there is an issue with the Bokeh version. `bokeh --version` returns 2.3.1. Is this maybe an issue between Jupyter_bokeh and bokeh? I think that bokeh is installed as a dependency for qiime2, is there a way to specifically call jupyer_bokeh?

Comment: I just tried with both Bokeh 2.2.3 and 2.3.3 with Jupyterlab 3.0.16 and they both worked. The version mismatch you report still points to some environement issue. Please ensure you have jupyter_bokeh >= 3.0 installed. When I installed jupyter_bokeh < 3 I saw similar results to what you describe.

Comment: Thank you - I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the difference between Bokeh, BokehJS, and Jupyter_bokeh. I currently have Jupyter_bokeh 3.0.2 and Bokeh 2.3.1. I don't see BokehJs in the package list. !bokeh info returns:

Python version      :  3.8.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 20 2021, 16:22:27) 
IPython version     :  7.22.0
Tornado version     :  6.1
Bokeh version       :  2.3.1
BokehJS static path :  /export/data1/sw/tag_conda/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bokeh/server/static
node.js version     :  v15.14.0
npm version         :  7.7.6

Comment: BokehJS is not a separate package. It is part of the Python package, or loaded over the network CDN. Either way the BokehJS version should (and must) always match the python package version. Which is why is you see a different BokehJS version than the installed Python package, there is definitely some environment issue going on. jupyter_bokeh is a jupyer extension that is required to load BokehJS in jupyterlab because that's just what jupyterlab demands. It's version is tied to the jupyterlab version.

Comment: bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE) worked for me in Jupyter lab Version 3.2.1